# Best way to integrate external mobile site in an app

Tags: mobile, cordova, jquery-mobile

I have a mobile website made in jQuery Mobile and I would like to integrate some parts of it in a Phone Gap mobile app.

The app will provide some *offline features* (using local html and JS) and will integrate with the mobile website sending forms and receiving its pages (that are already in jQuery Mobile).

What do you think is the best strategy to do this? Should I write services or should I keep the ongoing html pages?

Comment: if offline is the only criteria for your app, then you can use the webkit's offline caching capabilities. you dont need phonegap to give you the same. So the mobile web should still be a good to go with sqlite. :)

Comment: I see, but actually offline is one of the required features. Most of all, Phone Gap is required because the customer wish to have its app available on the app markets, they are not happy enough with the "add to home" bookmarked link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After seeing your comment above, Yes You can wrap it with phonegap and launch in app store. Then consider this, you can create services to return JSON(only for dynamic data) and load all your HTML templates on to the app (wrap with phonegap).

So static data/contents gets loaded from within the app and the dynamic content comes from server. Now enable offline caching for the dynamic contents which you want to enable for offline access.

TO enable offline access, you can either use webkit local storage(5Mb~50Mb) or a native phonegap plugin for more storage.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I found that was easier to write services to return JSON and use jQuery features to popolate jQuery Mobile pages than try to reuse the mobile web site HTML. Moreover, I could rewrite the mobile web site in order to reuse the services.